# Why is this id overriding my entire page's links?

Tags: css

This is a Chrome-only issue.  Though I'm only testing on IE10 and Chrome.  In IE the links show up fine.  This is only for VISITED links.  Links that I've never visited show up blue as normal.

```
#menu a:link,a:visited
{
display:inline-block;
text-transform:lowercase;
width:auto;
padding-left:25px;
padding-right:25px;
padding-top:6px;
padding-bottom:6px;
margin-left:4px;
margin-right:4px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#ffffff;
text-align:center;
background-color:#777777;
}
```

This HTML snippet is the only part of the code that ever refers to "menu".  I also tried debugging and found that it is specifically the "a:visited" part that is overriding all links on my page and turning them white.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css">
<title>Blah</title></head>
<body>
<ul><li style="display:inline-block;list-style-type:none;"><img src="logo.png" /></li><li style="display:inline-

block;list-style-type:none;"><div id="header">
<div id="menu">
      <div><img src="headline.png" /></div><ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li><li><a href="#">Products</a></li><li><a 

href="#">Design-a-Tee</a></li><li><a href="#">Reviews/Testimonials</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
</div>
</li></ul>
```

Comment: are you sure it's overriding all the anchor tags on your page?  or just those that are nested within the #menu div....?

Answer (score 2):

The comma (`,`) is a selector separator, it is used to define a list of selectors. So if you have:

```css
#menu a:link,a:visited
{
  /* whatever */
}
```

It is the same as having:

```css
#menu a:link
{
  /* whatever */
}
a:visited
{
  /* whatever */
}
```

So the `#menu` part only applies to the first selector. Think as if the comma *resets* the context.

So if you want to style `a` tags under `#menu`, use it in every selector

```css
#menu a:link,#menu a:visited { /* ... */
```

---

As for the browser considering all the link menus to be **`:visited`**, well, notice that they all point to local anchors: `<a href="#">`, so those anchors belong to the current page, thus they are "visited".

Change one `href` from `#` and you will see they aren't considered `:visited`: **[verify it in a demo](http://jsbin.com/vezosunu/1/edit)**.